# Center one <div> and float other right

Tags: css, html, floating

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Centering one div while another div is floated to the right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597256/centering-one-div-while-another-div-is-floated-to-the-right)

I'm trying to center container1 and float container2 to its right so that it's flowing off of the page slightly:

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7nJx.jpg

Unfortunately, container2 is hopping below and to the right of container1, as you can see in the site mock-up (link right below.)

SITE MOCK-UP:
http://ad313.samrandolphdesign.com/

CSS:

```
#container1 {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
}

#container2 {
    background-color: #CC9900;
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using absolute positioning instead of floating.

Something like:

```
#container1 {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: red;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
}

#container2 {
    background-color: #CC9900;
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -25%;
}​
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kH5DQ/)
EDIT: If you don't want absolute positioning for container1, just add `top: 0;` to container2

Comment: This is working! Thank you! I send hugs your way.

Answer (score 2):

wrap two divs inside another div. and make container 1 and container 2's display as inline-block.

something like this.

```
<div style="width: 2000px">
  <div id="container1" style="width: 990px; display: inline-block">
  </div>
  <div id="container2" style="width: 990px; display: inline-block">
  </div>
</div>
```

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sathyamoorthi/kH5DQ/2/)

Comment: if you want accurate answer, fiddle it

Comment: This is just throwing container1 all the way to the left and container1 is still placing itself at a weird place near the bottom (but strangely not under container1)

Comment: How does this "float container2 to its right so that it's flowing off of the page slightly?"

Comment: Of course, I love `inline-block` in comparison to the `float` bologne, but the problem arises if IE8 or lower must be supported. These do not support `inline-block`, alas.

Comment: yep!! i usually try everything in latest browsers. that could be the issue.

Comment: this answers fiddle working good in > IE7

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to move `#container2` above `#container1` in the markup so the floating top will be the top of `#container1` instead of after it. Second, you need to give `#container2` a negative margin-right to move it off screen.

```
#container2 {
background-color: #CC9900;
max-width: 600px;
width: 80%;
height: 100%;
padding-top: 60px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
text-align: center;
float: right;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: -300px;
}
```