# How to use GetSkeleton to Center one 'div' and float other 'div' right?

Tags: html, css, mobile-website, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I want to Center one div and float other right using any GetSkeleton. How do I do it using GetSkeleton or any other responsive framework?
[image]

My question is similar to this one [Center one <div> and float other right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967285/center-one-div-and-float-other-right)
but I am using GetSkeleton so the contents stack vertically on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out

```
<style type="text/css">
    .Menu {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 8%;
        right: 5%;
    }

    ul.Menu {
        -webkit-padding-start: 0;
        padding: 0;
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    ul.Menu li {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        .Menu {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 0%;
            right: 0px;
        }

        ul.Menu li {
            position: relative;
            right: 0px;
            text-align: left;
            text-align: center;
        }
    }

</style>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns" style="margin-top: 2%; text-align:center;">
            <img src="Content/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" style="width:15%; min-width:150px;" />
        </div>
        <ul class="Menu">
            <li>About us</li>
            <li>Careers</li>
            <li>Contact us</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```