# How can I center align an element correctly when it contains a child element floated right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I have a heading and an image. I want them to both appear on the same line as each other. I want the heading to be aligned center and the image to be aligned to the right.

My attempts so far have resulted in the following:
[image]

As you can see the heading 'Generate a URL' is pushed slightly to the left due to the image. How can I avoid this happening and keep it centered?

My HTML mark up is the following:

```
<h1 class="renault-title text-center bottom-margin-med">
    Generate a URL 
    <img class="pull-right" src="{{ asset('bundles/urlBuilder/images/renault_english_logo_desktop.png') }}" style="height:49px;"  alt="Renault logo">
</h1>
```

I am using Twitter Bootstrap. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Absolute Positioning. The image has to be taken out of the flow as it's dimensions affect the position of the "centered" item. Or use a background image. There's no real reason why you have to use an actual image there...is there?

Comment: Related if not a dulplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597256/centering-one-div-while-another-div-is-floated-to-the-right

Comment: Although floating takes an element out of the normal document flow, inline elements like text and images will flow around it. That is why you see your text offset to the left by the same amount as the floated image, the text is flowing around the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what the rest of your HTML looks like, you could use columns.  [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjXwYO?editors=1010).

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <h1 class="renault-title text-center bottom-margin-med">
      Generate a URL 
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <img class="pull-right" src="{{ asset('bundles/urlBuilder/images/renault_english_logo_desktop.png') }}" style="height:49px;"  alt="Renault logo">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to place `img` with `position: absolute`.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

h1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 170px; // Add indents equal to image width to avoid text overlapping.
  font-size: 24px;
}

h1 img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="renault-title text-center bottom-margin-med">
    Generate a URL 
    <img src="http://placehold.it/125x49/ffcc00/" style="height:49px;"  alt="Renault logo">
</h1>
```